# Using WebDeploy to create a server or site package

Tags: .net-4.0, webdeploy

Using Web Deploy I am having problems creating a import server or site package. There appears to be no documentation on this. I am using Windows 7 and IIS 7.5, Web Deploy 2.0.

I want to be able to create a deployment package to include the App Pool and Website information so can be installed at the root of IIS without having to manually create anything.

Answer (score 1):

The article [Synchronizing by using Packages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800880%28WS.10%29.aspx) details the basic [Web Deploy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568996%28WS.10%29.aspx) steps for creating a site or server package and then importing it on another server. If you want to package and deploy an IIS 7 Web server, you'd use the [webServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569021%28WS.10%29.aspx) provider. If you want to package and deploy an IIS 7 website, you'd use the [appHostConfig provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569080%28WS.10%29.aspx).

To include the app pool in the operation, you'll need to use the -enableLink:AppPoolExtension switch, like this:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:appHostConfig="Default Web Site" -dest:appHostConfig="Default Web Site",computerName=Server2 -enableLink:AppPoolExtension
```

For more on the enableLink setting, see [Web Deploy Operation Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx). For more on link extensions, see the [Web Deploy Link Extensions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569028%28WS.10%29.aspx) page.